# Flutter: Is there a way to get quit event in web application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to call an API when the user closes or reloads the webpage(web application).

**listen event**

```
html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen(
  (event) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> _exit = await callApi(CloseRoomAPI);
    print(_exit);
  },
);
```

**Call API function**

```
    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> callApi(String _url) async {
  final client = new http.Client();

  final connection = await client.get(_url);

  if (connection.statusCode == 200) {
    return jsonDecode(connection.body.toString());
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) - YMMV. Might use that term to find something Flutter-specific.